# Scaling data in R ignoring specific columns

Tags: r

I have some data in csv format I want to use for predictive modeling. I read the data in R and apply some simple preprocessing (ommitting NA etc.). Before I want to train a SVM classifier I want to scale the data using the scale(x) function. The problem is that my label column is part of the dataset. How can I tell R to ignore that columns? Or what is best practice here?

```
label,  X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn
Y,  34, 74, 29, ..., 47
N,  88, 46, 95, ..., 33
N,  58, 78, 25, ..., 68
Y,  33, 56, 61, ..., 13
```

If I try:

```
x <- scale(trouble[,-c(1)])
trouble <- x
summary(trouble)
rm(x);
```

The first column is deleted and gone for good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do partial assignment:

```
trouble[, -c(1)] <- scale(trouble[, -c(1)])
```

Comment: Or, with a list of column names: `trouble[,which(!names(trouble) %in% c("label"))] <- scale(trouble[,which(!names(trouble) %in% c("label"))])`

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that `scale` also operates on `data.frame` objects.

```
dtf <- read.table(text = "label,  X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn
+ Y,  34, 74, 29, ..., 47
+ N,  88, 46, 95, ..., 33
+ N,  58, 78, 25, ..., 68
+ Y,  33, 56, 61, ..., 13
+ ", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
> (dtf <- dtf[-5])
  label X1 X2 X3 Xn
1     Y 34 74 29 47
2     N 88 46 95 33
3     N 58 78 25 68
4     Y 33 56 61 13
> (dtf_scales <- scale(dtf[-1]))
             X1         X2         X3         Xn
[1,] -0.7435537  0.6958884 -0.7210036  0.2913066
[2,]  1.3422592 -1.1598139  1.3039428 -0.3128849
[3,]  0.1834743  0.9609887 -0.8437277  1.1975938
[4,] -0.7821798 -0.4970631  0.2607886 -1.1760155
attr(,"scaled:center")
   X1    X2    X3    Xn 
53.25 63.50 52.50 40.25 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
      X1       X2       X3       Xn 
25.88919 15.08863 32.59346 23.17146
```

So there...

**EDIT:**

You can use negative subscripts only with numeric indices. If you pass a column name, you can't use negative subscripts, so `dtf[-"label"]` will not work. In that case, you may use `which`, `%in%`, and focus on logical indices.