# R scale function not working from csv file import

Tags: r

i have same problem like this topic [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107157/adding-labels-to-cluster,
i followed the replied answer still not working on me then
try to find another solution from this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120984/scaling-data-in-r-ignoring-specific-columns also still not working

so far my code just follow from this topic [https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering and [https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering as shown below

```
1. library(tidyverse)
2. library(cluster)
3. library(factoextra)
4. dataMCU = read.csv("MCU180721.csv")
5. dataMCU <- na.omit(dataMCU)
6. dataMCU <- scale(dataMCU)
```

this line number: 6 failed to proceed since show error like this Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

for addition information my table in csv file describe below
precint, green, yelloe, orange, red
oregon, 6, 7, 8, 9

my question is how to resolve this problem.
recently i've tried with this code `dataMCU<-dataMCU[,c(-1)]` before run `scale()`
this solution works but not as expected. since i wish to have same result just like [https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering and [https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering

for additional information:
[image: Name of Town as Label] this from [https://afit-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering

but my code always show like below picture
[image: Only show number not name of city]

Comment: can you add dput(head(dataMCU)) you have after line 4?

Comment: dataMCU <- dput(head(dataMCU)) result show below
structure(list(Precint = c("Oregon", "Iowa", "Chicago",
"Boston", "Idaho", "Texax"), Green = c(77L, 17L, 108L, 27L,
68L, 17L), Yellow = c(25L, 25L, 4L, 28L, 28L, 7L), Orange = c(1L,
7L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 2L), Red = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA,
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data frame has the character vector. You can have the states as row names and remove the first column.

```
rownames(dataMCU) <- dataMCU$Precint
dataMCU <- dataMCU[,-1]
```

Then, you can remove NA rows and scale the data frame.

```
dataMCU <- na.omit(dataMCU)
dataMCU <- scale(dataMCU)
```

Proceed with distance matrix and clustering:

```
distance <- get_dist(dataMCU)
fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))

clust <- kmeans(dataMCU, centers = 2, nstart = 25)

fviz_cluster(clust, data = dataMCU)
```

P.S.: To avoid the manual workaround, you can simply import csv file as

```
dataMCU = read.csv("fMCU180721.csv", row.names = 1, header= TRUE)
```

Edit:

Importing the csv with row names:

```
dataMCU = read.csv("DataPrecint.csv", row.names=1, header=TRUE)
dataMCU <- na.omit(dataMCU)
dataMCU <- scale(dataMCU)
distance <- get_dist(dataMCU)
fviz_dist(distance, gradient=list(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red"))
k4 <- kmeans(dataMCU, centers=4, nstart=25)
str(k4)
k4
fviz_cluster(k4, data = dataMCU)
```

Comment: `code`
    dataMCU = read.csv("precints.csv")
     rownames(dataMCU) <- dataMCU$precints
    dataMCU <- dataMCU[-1]
    dataMCU <- na.omit(dataMCU)
    dataMCU <- scale(dataMCU)
    distance <- get_dist(dataMCU)
    fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))
    k4 <- kmeans(dataMCU, centers=4, nstart=25)
    str(k4)
    k4
    fviz_cluster(k4, data=dataMCU)
    `code`

thank you for your help. this code works but the result (plot) still not displaying the city name as label. the plot still displaying number as label.

Comment: It's not precints, but Precint. Objects and variables are case sensitive. Try rownames(dataMCU) <- dataMCU$Precint

Comment: $Precints = this is variabel from this read.csv("Precints.csv")?

Comment: [link] https://pastebin.com/Acb0KciR i followed your instruction since the variable is case sensitive, the code on the link. but the result same not displaying the name of town

Comment: Check my edit. If you are importing csv with row names, you don't have to rename the rows and remove the columns.

Comment: can this function fviz_dist(distance, gradient=list(low="green", mid="yellow", high="red")) handle 4 categoris for instance green, yellow, orange and red?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The gradient argument can be of three colours only.

Comment: i see. we hope R will try to adjust this in future